# Click/Hover effect on TextBlock in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation

I have a menu build from `TextBlock`s in a `StackPanel`.

I would like the `TextBlock`s to animate when they are tapped. Pretty much like how the stock apps animate on click in menus.

The documents I've read seems to create an animation per each named item. That seems a little backwards.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Your questions is pretty vague - so some code as a starting point would help.

Comment: @ColinE I've been trying to add animations using Blend and the states, but all I've seem to accomplish is to ruin my prism interactivity bindings. :/

I guess something like <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"> is what I expect to work with, but I'm thinking about why it can't be as easy as hover in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the TiltEffect.cs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941094

Answer (score 0):

Creating an animation per item is not so crazy. You can simply iterate over the `Children` of the `StackPanel` adding the animation to each in code.

Comment: Yes, but how? The examples where so convoluted I can't take them seriously.

Comment: I just found that VisualStateGroups can be nested in global Styles. That doesn't seem that bad.